# Saving to database in Django tests when using ThreadPoolExecutor

Tags: python, django, postgresql, concurrency, django-testing

I have an issue trying to use Django's TestCase to test a piece of code which is parallelized with ThreadPoolExecutor. On the server everything is working fine (at least no known issues so far testing "by hand"), but when I run my tests their execution just gets stuck on the save() method.
So, basically I have something like this:

```
class A(models.Model):
    # something here
    def start(self):
        objectsB = []
        for i in range(n):
            objectB = B(i)
            objectsB.append(objectB)
        results = []
        with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=len(objectsB)) as executor:
            futures = [executor.submit(objectB.start) for objectB in objectsB]
            for future in concurrent.futures.as_completed(futures):
                results.append(future.result())
        return results


class B(models.Model):
    # something here
    def start(self):
        # some logic here (including reading from database)
        response = requests.post('http://www.externalapi.com')
        # some logic here
        print('during test this is printed')
        self.save()
        print('during test this is never reached')
```

When I used the same code without concurrency, just executing `objectB.start` sequentially, tests worked fine. Reading calls to database in method `start` of objectsB also seem to work. I am using Django 1.9, python 3.5, postgresql 9.5.3 and nose for running tests. Any help or thoughts about why such approach might be wrong are appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say what's happening without the actual code, but my guess would be that you're experiencing a deadlock in your database transactions. Django's `TestCase` runs each testcase in a transaction. You can try and use `TransactionTestCase` to test transaction-sensitive code. If that doesn't fix it, I'd need more information about the actual code.

Comment: Thank you, @knbk. I did not provide actual code because it would take too much space, while the scope of the problem seems to be limited to `start` of B. Moreover, if I remove all logic from there and leave only `self.save()`, the problem persists. Subclassing my test case class from TransactionTestCase instead of TestCase makes tests pass smoothly. But now after all the tests on destroying database stage I often get an error from postgresql, saying that it's being used in another seance.

Comment: I had this same problem and resolved it with `TransactionTestCase` as mentioned in the other comments. There is a [warning in the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/testing/overview/#rollback-emulation) that should be pointed out: "Any initial data loaded in migrations will only be available in `TestCase` tests and not in `TransactionTestCase` tests". You can set `serialized_rollback = True` if needed to work around this.

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Put your test in this structure:

```
from django.test import TransactionTestCase

class AsyncTestCase(TransactionTestCase):

    def test_my_code(self):
        ...
```

This keeps the data in memory and doesn't do a commit to the database. I'm guessing that the threaded code uses a different database connection during tests.